# update mysql, new data starts at unique id 1

Tags: php, mysql, database

I would like to know how to update my database table with new data but having the latest data be at the top with the unique id starting at 1.  Here's what I mean:

First insert query, for example, inserts 3 article topics:

```
id        article
 1        firstNews
 2        secondNews
 3        thirdNews
```

Then the next time I run a Cron job to check for new articles, for example two new articles appear, I want the two new articles to be in the beginning of the table, like this:

```
id        article
 1        NewArticle1
 2        NewArticle2
 3        firstNews
 4        secondNews
 5        thirdNews
```

Hope that made sense.  This might be a bad way to do it, I guess I could have a column with insert date() and then get the data out OrderBy date but it has to be an easier way to do this.  I think this would be the easiest to output the most recent data from the table...

If I do ORDER BY DESC, it would output NewArticle2 before NewArticle1, which would defeat the purpose...

```
id       article
 1       firstNews
 2       secondNews
 3       thirdNews
 4       NewArticle1
 5       NewArticle2
```

So by DESC, id 5 would be the first one output...I was really hoping there was a way around this...

Comment: changing the ID is a bad idea (you will not be able to easily link to one of your articles for example), a lot of work (for you and the database) and unnecessary (you can just do `ORDER BY id DESC`).

Comment: Re-arrange a table primary index isn't an option. For example when using URLs `news.php?p=id=2` would result in different newsitems each day. Just sort your results based on a descending id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never do this. Just insert at the end, and to get the latest articles, use a query:

```
SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC;
```

In general: Don't fit the data to your query, fit the query to your data. The id is not a position or number, it uniquely identifies that row of data.

Comment: If I do it that way, then NewArticle1 will have an id of 4 and NewArticle2 will have an id of 5.  If I ORDER BY DESC, NewArticle2 will be ahead of NewArticle1 so therefore that wouldn't be the latest...

Comment: When refreshing your results, first save all items in an array (order Newsitem1, Newsitem2), then use array_reverse() to reverse the order. Loop the reversed array and Newsitem 2 will be inserted before newsitem 1 and thus giving you the result you want.

Comment: I really like this idea of reversing the order in an array and then inserting into the DB.  The should get me the newest item to be the last id.  Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Date columns and sort on that. Or just sort by ID descending.

It's rarely a good idea to change a PK in place. Not least, you mah have child tables using that PK and maybe history tables too

Note that there is no implicit order to a SQL table: you always need an ORDER BY to guarantee the resultset order

Answer (score 0):

You should add another column specifically for sorting, e.g. a date. and add an `INDEX` on it.

Then the query becomes:

```
SELECT * 
FROM news
ORDER BY newsdate DESC
```

*Latest news comes first*

If there are two news items that could be posted at exactly the same time, you may wish to include a secondary sort:

```
ORDER BY newsdate DESC, id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be your concern at all.

**ID is not a number nor a position** by any means. It's just an **unique identifier**.

Means every database row sticks to it's id forever. While you want to assign your "unique" id to the every newcoming news, which makes no sense.

So, just have usual autoincremented id and select it using `ORDER BY id DESC` to have latest entries first.